# Need notification of styles of a WPF control

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I need my application to be notified when style is changed of a control. I need to to do some actions when the style is changed of a WPF control. Can I apply some eventtriggers or notify is some way.

Best Regards

Comment: What do you mean by "When the style is changed"? Because you can't dynamically update the style of a control. You can update some properties based on triggers but you can't reassign a new style to a control.

Comment: May be [OnApplyTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.onapplytemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you need. That method of the Control gets called each time the style is set.

Comment: @Evangelink You can change the `Style` of any WPF control [as many times as you want](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683(v=vs.110).aspx) in your XAML or C# code.

Comment: @haindl Actually every control has a style set once and only once into xaml. Multiple instances can have different styles but one `TextBox` has only one style. Not true if you change it from code.

Comment: @Evangelink Changing styles [dynamically in code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18200902/changing-the-styles-at-runtime-in-wpf) has been done [many times](http://www.vitoshacademy.com/c-wpf-changing-styles-in-wpf-setter-property-usage-style-declaration-in-xaml/). One `TextBox` surely can have only one style at one given point in time but this style can change dynamically as often as you want.

Comment: @haindl Yep. Look back at my comment. Just sayin it is not possible in pure XAML.

Comment: @Evangelink A `Style` is just a normal `DependencyProperty`. It can be set and changed in XAML using a `Binding`. Look [here for an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/410681/6682181) or [here for another example](https://brettedotnet.wordpress.com/2009/07/22/binding-wpf-style/). You can also use a `Trigger/DataTrigger` to set or change the whole instance of the `Style`. Look [here for an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25759625/6682181). I think the latter fully qualifies as 100% "pure XAML". So please explain it to me: Why shouldn't it be possible? Doesn't it compile? Any runtime errors?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possible solutions.

First you could subscribe a change handler to the `Style` property of your control if want to get notified somewhere in your C# code:

```
DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(Button.StyleProperty, typeof(Button))
    .AddValueChanged(btn, (s, e) =>
    {
        // Style has changed.
    });
```

(Don't forget to call `.RemoveValueChanged()` after you're done.)

Another way would be to create a `Binding` with a source path set to the `Style` of your control. The binding target could for example be some kind of custom control or a ViewModel where you want to react to the change. Or if you don't have any of these available, you could just set the binding target to some `Tag` property and use a `ValueConverter` to intercept the change using something like `Tag="{Binding Style, ElementName=btn, Converter={StaticResource MyStyleInterceptor}}"`.

You could also create a custom attached property for this purpose if you don't want to abuse `Tag`.