# Change button text and color in a datagrid. WPF c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a datagrid table in WPF which is bound to a model. How do I change the button text, and color  based on a bool property from the model.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="FileReviewGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" CanUserSortColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True"
                      ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}"
                  materialDesign:DataGridAssist.CellPadding="13 8 8 8" materialDesign:DataGridAssist.ColumnHeaderPadding="8" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Background="{x:Null}">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Button Click="Decrypt_Click" Height="25" Margin="0,-10" >
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="FileExport" />
                                            <TextBlock>Decrypt</TextBlock>
                                        </StackPanel>

                                    </Button>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can bind Button's **'Background'** and **'Text'** properties to properties in the model and when your bool is changed you can change Background and Text properties in the code behind. Provide more code to get a more accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

you should create tow datatemplates one for the first style wich will selected by default and the second for the true value and you can hide it or show it depending on the bool value
you can also create a style and bind it to the model

Comment: How do I do that.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25758592/changing-style-from-inside-a-datatrigger